# I cannot import BOSHConnection from smack library

Tags: android, smack

I am trying to use BOSHConnection in eclipse but I cannot import org.jivesoftware.smack.BOSHConnection. I downloaded Smack 3.4.1 from " http://svn.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp " but that version does not contains BOSHConnection. Which version of smack I should use?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadasmackandroid16jar.htm

I am using this one right here. It's slightly outdated compared to the new 8.* version, but seems to work fine.